# Discord bot failing to find results in Sqlite3 database despite search params being valid

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, python-3.6, discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot that takes a input from a user via a command and searches a sqlite3 database I made for that input.

The following is the code that I am having trouble with

```
@bot.command()
async def searchip(ctx,ipadd):
   sqlite_file = 'proxys.sqlite'  
   conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
   c = conn.cursor()
   k = c.execute("SELECT orderid FROM proxy WHERE ip_address = ?",[k])
   ds = k.fetchall()
   for g in ds:
       g = ''.join(g)
       g = g.replace(" ( ", " ")
       g = g.replace(" )"," ")
       g = g.replace(",", " ")
       g = g.strip()
       print(g)
```

What this code does is it takes ipadd from the command and connects to the proxy database I created. I then try to select the orderid associated with that ip address (TEXT field with a order id in there) in the database and prints out the result. However whenever I try do do

```
!search fakeeee:fake:fake:fake
```

it prints out [] meaning it didn't get any results back. Why is that happening when "fakeeee:fake:fake:fake" is in the database.

P.S: The input in the database has no spaces before or after in the field (so it is not an issue with spacing etc)

[EDIT]: As suggested instead of

```
k = c.execute("SELECT orderid FROM proxy WHERE ip_address = ?",[k])
```

I tried this:

```
k = c.execute("SELECT orderid FROM proxy WHERE ip_address = ?",(k,))
```

However it still returned []

Comment: I think you shouldn't be passing the parameter as a list: `execute("...", ipadd)`

Comment: If you `print(repr(ipadd))` what does the string you're using to search the batabase look like?